# Sharepoint-enterprise: Making sharepoint My profile site?

Tags: 2010

Sharepoint-enterprise
I am very new to sharepoint and need to implement the following?

I need to create a subsite or a page(whichever is suitable) for each member of a team(total members around 30), which will include their personal details along with a set of fun questions which they can edit/answer.

Restrictions: 
1>  **My site** is not available to us otherwise it wasn't required.
2>  I cannot use any kind of coding and I have to accomplish it with the available webparts.

I tried several webparts like Infopath, Notes etc, but didn't find a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a new Page Layout with SharePoint Designer, accompanied with a new Content Type. Content Type would contain the actual fields where people type in their answers, and Page Layout would contain the questions, and the fields of the content type.

Every person would have own Page, and they would modify content by taking the Page into Edit mode, typing in their answers in the text boxes, and saving the page.

Pages are located in the Pages library of the site, and it will need to be a Publishing site (=Publishing features enabled).

AAND! If SharePoint Designer is out of the question, I'd just create simple HTML table that I would include in normal content area, or Content Editor Web Part. Table would contain two columns, left would have the question, and right would have answers. Obviously people can mess up and modify also the question column, but that's the cost you have to pay for not being able to use dev tools.

ALSO! Other option might be to create a site using Team Site template per person, and include a custom list with items having fields for question and answer. Then add normal List View Web Part on the front page of the team site, and list the question/answer pairs. You could even include a Edit button on each row, or enable inline editing. Users would be able to modify the questions, but you'd have control of the layout. After you've finished creating the template, you can save it as Site Template and create the rest 29 sites from that. Just remember to include content when you save the site as template.

Phew.

Comment: Thanks Jussi, What I did is created a list with columns being all the questions. I modified the view of the list to display only the names and used customized form to make a fun page. Now each individual can add hi/herself. One reason I couldn't go for a site for each person b'coz, I dont have the permission to savepage/site as a template.           I really appreciate your response to my query as this assignment was on my head all the time and your approaches gave me diiferent views to look at.. Thanks again